# click event stopped triggering after disabling sort in jQuery tablesorter

Tags: html, jquery, click, tablesorter, disable

**.click()** event stopped working after disabling sort of a particular header cell in a HTML table. **jquery.tablesorter** is the jQuery plugin used to sort the data in table.

Comment: We need to see all relevant information, like html jquery

Comment: Please post your code of click event or try like this $(document).on('click', '.your_class', function(){ //your code });

Answer (score 0):

Reason: click binding is removed by tablesorter since it rebuilds the HTML table header.

Solution: Set headerTemplate option to an empty string ("") in **jquery.tablesorter.js** file

Change **headerTemplate:"{content}"** to **headerTemplate: ""**